# How can I send email to each user separately listed in gridview by clicking on mail button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, gridview, smtp

**Currently whole grid is sending to all users. I want to send email to each user separately and only their data should be email to them.**

**home aspx. page**

```
    <asp:Button ID="mail" runat="server" Text="Mail" CssClass="button" OnClick="mail_Click" Style="margin-left: 10px; width: 100px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;" />
```

on mail button event fires, whole grid send to all users. 
**I want when mail button event fires, firstly it should get email address from database against username then mail to 1st user in grid user then 2nd and so on.**

**home aspx.cs page**

```
 protected void mail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
            {
                System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm frm = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm();
                grdTask.Parent.Controls.Add(frm);
                frm.Attributes["runat"] = "server";
                frm.Controls.Add(grdTask);
                grdTask.Columns[7].Visible = false;
                frm.RenderControl(hw);
                StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
                MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(AppSettings.FromMail, AppSettings.ToMail);
                mm.Subject = "Today Status";
                mm.Body = "Hi All, <br /> <br /> Below are the task detail for today:<br /> " + sw.ToString() + "<br /><br />Thanks<br />";
                mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Host = AppSettings.SmtpHost; //"smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
                NetworkCred.UserName = AppSettings.NetworkCredUsername;
                NetworkCred.Password = AppSettings.NetworkCredPassword;
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
                smtp.Port = AppSettings.SmtpPort;//587;
                smtp.Send(mm);
                Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How users are displayed in GridView? Show the markup. Also is the Button you mentioned part of GridView or it lies outside GridView ?

Comment: Button is outside the grid  & Users are displayed in grid view against their tasks.
i.e..
Username ! Project Name ! Task Description  ! Est Time ! Act Time ! Completed ! Comments

Comment: And the Button ? it lies outside GridView ?

Comment: yeah, it lies outside the gridivew

Comment: Ok. Then you should try looping over GridView Rows, check the User in each row, send the mail ...

Comment: I'm sharing gridview code

Comment: i tried this but it fails.

            GridView gv = new GridView();
            //HiddenField lnk = (HiddenField)e.Row.FindControl("hdnEmail");
            string username = "";

Comment: foreach (GridViewRow gr in grdTask.Rows)
            {
                Label lbl = (Label)gr.FindControl("lblUserId");
                if (username != lbl.Text)
                {
                    username = lbl.Text;

                    foreach (GridViewRow gr1 in grdTask.Rows)
                    {
                        Label lbl1 = (Label)gr.FindControl("lblUserId");
                        if (username == lbl1.Text)
                        {
                            gv.Rows.add();
                        }
                    }